# How to reorder objects in an array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an array of objects. The objects within the array represent car model and the price. I would like to reorder the objects within the array , so that the list should follow  models SEDAN, followed by CITROEN, then SUZUKI , followed by MERCEDES.

The following is my code.

```
     enum Model {
      SEDAN = 'SEDAN',
      MERCEDES = 'MERCEDES',
      CITROEN = 'CITROEN',
      SUZUKI = 'SUZUKI',
    }
    
    interface CarModelPrice {
      model :  Model;
      price : number;
    }
    
    const sedan: CarModelPrice = {
      model: Model.SEDAN,
      price: 25
    };
    
    const mercedes: CarModelPrice = {
      model: Model.MERCEDES,
      price: 20
    };
    
    const citroen: CarModelPrice = {
      model: Model.CITROEN,
      price: 15
    };
    
    const suzuki: CarModelPrice = {
      model: Model.SUZUKI,
      price: 30
    };

    let carModelPriceArr : CarModelPrice[] = [ sedan, mercedes, citroen, suzuki ];
    
    
    console.log(carModelPriceArr);

[{"model":"SEDAN","price":25},{"model":"MERCEDES","price":20},{"model":"CITROEN","price":15},{"model":"SUZUKI","price":30}]
```

up on sorting carModelPriceArr i would expect  the following result.

```
[{"model":"SEDAN","price":25},{"model":"CITROEN","price":15},{"model":"SUZUKI","price":30},{"model":"MERCEDES","price":20}]
```

How can i do the custom sorting  on the array carModelPriceArr?

following is the typescript playground for this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4zvofc

appreciate if you can help
thank you

Comment: I don't get what's your sort criteria

Comment: sort criteria is SEDAN,  CITROEN, SUZUKI , MERCEDES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a priority level as a number for every model, then sort like this:

```js
const cars = [{"model":"SEDAN","price":25},{"model":"MERCEDES","price":20},{"model":"CITROEN","price":15},{"model":"SUZUKI","price":30}];

const priority = {
  SEDAN: 1,
  CITROEN: 2,
  SUZUKI: 3,
  MERCEDES: 4
}

const result = cars.sort(({ model: modelA }, { model: modelB }) => priority[modelA] - priority[modelB]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna do 

Comment: could some one explain what is written within the sort ? thank you

Comment: There is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the function  parameters to retrieve only the `model` property of the two cars being compared, respectively `modelA` and `modelB`. The return value is the result of a substraction: either a positive or negative number based on the difference of priority

Comment: bless you ...a heartfelt prayer from those who struck on this